# Looking for general feedback on a URL-parsing script of mine (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, text-parsing

I'm fairly new to Javascript, and assembled the following (part is from an example online, rest is by me):

This works reliably, I'm just wondering how many best-practices I'm violating. If someone is nice enough to provide general feedback about the latter part of this script, that would be appreciated.

The two included functions are to (1) capture the incoming website visitor's referral data on a page, including URL query strings for analytics, and store it to a cookie. (2) When the visitor completes a form, the script will read the cookie's URL value, parse this URL into segments, and write the segment data to pre-existing hidden inputs on a form.

Example URL this would capture and parse: http://example.com/page?utm_source=google&utm_medium=abc&utm_campaign=name1&utm_adgroup=name2&utm_kw=example1&kw=example2&mt=a&mkwid=xyz&pcrid=1234

```
function storeRef() { //this function stores document.referrer to a cookie if the cookie is not already present
    var isnew = readCookie('cookiename'); //set var via read-cookie function's output
        if (isnew == null) {
            var loc=document.referrer; 
            createCookie('cookiename',loc,0,'example.com'); //create cookie via function with name, value, days, domain 
        }
}

function printQuery() { //function to parse cookie value into segments
    var ref=readCookie('cookiename'); //write cookie value to variable
    var refElement = ref.split(/[?&]/); //create array with variable data, separated by & or ?. This is for domain info primarily.
    var queryString = {}; //From http://stevenbenner.com/2010/03/javascript-regex-trick-parse-a-query-string-into-an-object/
    ref.replace(
        new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"),
        function($0, $1, $2, $3) { queryString[$1] = $3; } 
    );
//write segments to form field names below.     
    document.getElementsByName('example1')[0].value = refElement[0]; //exampleX is a form hidden input's name. I can not use getElementById here.
//need to be able to manually define these, which is why they aren't in a loop, though I'm not sure how to loop an array referenced in this way
    document.getElementsByName('example2')[0].value = queryString['utm_source']; 
    document.getElementsByName('example3')[0].value = queryString['utm_medium'];
    document.getElementsByName('example4')[0].value = queryString['utm_term'];
    document.getElementsByName('example5')[0].value = queryString['utm_content'];
    document.getElementsByName('example6')[0].value = queryString['utm_campaign'];
    document.getElementsByName('example7')[0].value = queryString['utm_adgroup'];
    document.getElementsByName('example8')[0].value = queryString['utm_kw'];
    document.getElementsByName('example9')[0].value = queryString['kw'];
    document.getElementsByName('example10')[0].value = queryString['mt'];
    document.getElementsByName('example11')[0].value = queryString['mkwid'];
    document.getElementsByName('example12')[0].value = queryString['pcrid'];
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

why would you need to use a cookie to store the data for that, if unless you wanna keep track of the visitors visiting to your site?

Comment: I realize it's odd. This is basically a workaround for a current limitation in a product, while others are working on a real fix. Long story, really. A client wants referral data (from the initial non-domain referrer) stored in a form submit.